# How do I make Whatsapp read multiple similar databases?

Tags: internal-storage, whatsapp-messenger

Recently I got a new phone,and finally discovered that the Whatsapp FAQ teaches how to transfer messages from one phone to another,assuming both is android.

So, I managed to transfer from my old phone-1 (Samsung Galaxy Ace 2) to my new phone and the Whatsapp manage to read it(with 9 Databases).

Then I use my old phone-2 (A type of PHICOMM phone made in China but it is an Android phone) to transfer the messages to my new phone.The problem is,when I try to transfer the old phone-2 database,the database have the same name as the old phone-1 data base,so the file manager says to overwrite or replace but I didn't do both of them because if I overwrite, I doubt the Whatsapp being able to read it. Instead, I renamed the file to `msgstore.db2.crypt8`.

The Whatsapp read the `msgstore.db2.crypt8` instead and cannot read all at once.

Here is the 10 database names:

- msgstore.db2.crypt8 (The Old Phone 2)(3.44mb) msgstore.db.crypt8 (The
  Old Phone 1)(And all below this onwards is also Old Phone 1,but
  during the time I use Old Phone 1,I already tranfer them to the SD
  card to release space.)(10.48mb)
- msgstore-2015-06-16.1.db.crypt8(10.48mb)
- msgstore-2015-06-16.1.db.crypt (Hm...no "8" at the back?)(9.22mb)
- msgstore-2015-06-11.1.db.crypt8(12.70mb)
- msgstore2015-06-13.1.db.crypt8(12.73mb)
- msgstore2015-06-14.1.db.crypt8(12.75mb)
- msgstore2015-06-09.1.db.crypt8(12.66mb)
- msgstore2015-06-12.1.db.crypt8(12.73mb)
- msgstore2015-06-15.1.db.crypt8(12.76mb)

> Question is, What name should I keep to the file msgstore.db2.crypt8 in order for the Whatsapp to read all these 10 databases?

FYI: I transferred all of the database files to my new phone's internal storage.

**Update 1**:Done an extra research only to find out that the file named "msgstore.db.crypt8" can only be read and those with format "msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD" are the backup messaged done on 4am and will show up for 7 days.So,how do I rename such that Whatsapp read both "msgstore.db2.crypt8" and "msgstore.db.cyrpt8"?(FAQ Link: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/?forum=android&entry=20887921&l=fi)

**Update 2**:I used Old Phone 1 first,then Old phone 2 then the Old Phone 1 back then the New Phone.

The Old Phone 1 databases is from 2011 to 2014 December then Jump to 2015 May-June.

The Old Phone 2 databases is 2014 December-2015 May.

Comment: You first had the Old Phone 2, you used whatsapp on that. Ok. Than you buyed new phone, ironically, Old Phone 1. But you didnt transfered the msg database. And then finally you bought another new phone and now wish to intergrate both msg database. Am i right?
Also, did you used same Number in all three phone (Ofc you can only use one number in one phone at a time), And i also wish to know the time differnce between these phones, ie "I last used WA on OP2 on __, OP1 __, and New phone on __. This is to make sure of the updates WA may have got in between

Comment: @Abhioxic Apologies for the Old Phone confusion but I used the Old phone 1 then Old Phone 2 then the New phone.All of them have the same number.I will update them now

Comment: @Abhioxic Yeah I didnt transfer the msg bases during Old Phone 1 and 2.When I got my new phone,I finally found a way to transfer it

Comment: Do you have root access in those phones? The msgstore.db you are talking about i believe can only be found in data folder of WA(and you require root for that). Finally, if you have root, you can easily get (or pull using ADB) the `msgstore.db` which is un-encypted. The last thing is I highly doubt that the encryption method used on the oldest phone and the old phone are same at all.

Comment: @Abhioxic  I do not have root access.I can transfer that msgstore.db.crypt8,and Whatsapp read this.Of course I cannot read what is inside that.You can easy find these at "Your Files">Device Storage>Whatsapp>Databases.Try it for your phone too then you will know what I am talking about

Comment: @Abhioxic https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/?forum=android&entry=20887921&l=fi is what I just searched for Update 1.It tells how the Whatsapp reads the folder.So I was wondering how do I make the "msgstore.db.crypt8" and "msgstore.db2.crypt8" both readable by whatsapp,Or how can I merge these 2 files together?

Comment: See, `msgstore.db` and `msgstore.db.cypt8` as well as `msgstore2015-06-15.1.db.crypt8` are all different databases. I am talking about 1st one. Also please add the given link in the question and any other info you can give.

Comment: @Abhioxic I see.I tot "msgstore.db" and "msgstore.db.crypt8" are the same.Though,what is the point of unencrypting msgstore.db?What I know here is that I have to find a way to merge "msgstore.db.crypt8" and what I renamed as "msgstore.db2.crypt8" so that they became 1 "msgstore.db.crypt8" as whatsapp ONLY can read "msgstore.db.crypt8"

Comment: @Abhioxic Wait first,Im just 14 who doesnt understand coding yet.Lemme search what is encrypting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24873/discussion-between-abhioxic-and-ministic2001).